# WideImage library not included on IPhone

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wideimage

i have a really strange problem. Im using the WideImage Library on my Server to manipulate Images. The Library is included in a php-File. Like this:

```
define('DOCROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'); 
require_once(DOCROOT . 'inc/wideimage/WideImage.php');
```

It works fine for all Desktop-Browsers, but on the IPhone it doesnt. The Problem occurs only with the WideImage Library, i also included another File and it worked without any problem.

I really dont understand why this happens, because PHP is a server-orientated Language and should be affacted by the type of device....

Here is the process:
In my index.php i call via ajax the image-manipulation.php which includes the WideImage Library -> the result (manipulated image) is given back to the index.php as JSON-String.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: The problem is not in wideimage, but elsewhere, probably in JS...

Comment: In found the solution in this post: stackoverflow.com/a/1964679/1964981 I had a problem with realtive and absolute URL -> had to use relative not absolute URLs. (The Problem only occured via 3G Connection)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to force a Content-Type header before returning your image data? it could be a browser issue.